# transform colors in colorbar, not the ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, transform, normalization, colorbar

When using a custom normalization, for instance `PowerNorm`, we can adjust the mapping between values and the colors. If we then show a corresponding colorbar, we can see the change when observing the ticks (compare left and right plot in the following picture).

Is there a way to use the normalization like on the left, but then have a colorbar where the *colours* are "squished" to one end, but the ticks remain equidistant (like on the right side)?

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import PowerNorm
x, _ = np.meshgrid(*2*(np.linspace(-1, 1, 100),))
# with normalization: transformation is applied to image as desired, but the ticks at the colorbar are not equidistant
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(x, norm=PowerNorm(gamma=4, vmin=-1, vmax=1))
plt.colorbar()  
# without normalization
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(x)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't know pyplot very well, but in MATLAB I'd try to set the color bar's y axis to linear.

Comment: @CrisLuengo That does indeed work, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to set the y axis of the color bar to be linear:

```py
cb = plt.colorbar() 
cb.ax.set_yscale('linear')
```

[image]